# Are white hat hackers rewarded for identifying genAI's vulnerabilities?

Tags: jailbreak, genai-ecosystem

At some sites I use, [white hat hackers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_hat_(computer_security)) get certain rewards or "flair" for identifying and reporting vulnerabilities before they can be exploited in nefarious ways.  The website [llm-attacks.org](https://llm-attacks.org/), for instance, highlights a vulnerability for ChatGPT-3.5-Turbo, but which can be used for other LLMs.  The authors' research was aimed at highlighting and combating the vulnerability:

> Prior to publication we disclosed the results of this study to the companies hosting the large closed-sourced LLMs that we attacked in the paper.

I'm wondering if, in general, white hat hackers are rewarded (such as through trinkets like flair, or even outright paid for their service) for identifying vulnerabilities.  I have in mind major LLMs, like ChatGPT.

**Question**: Are white hat hackers rewarded for identifying genAI's vulnerabilities?

I asked [poe.com's ChatGPT](https://poe.com/ChatGPT), and it said *I do not have any information*.  Google just gave me examples of white hat hackers attempting to use ChatGPT for identifying vulnerabilities.

Comment: I don't believe it's useful to ask ChatGPT about the *GenAI hype* as the data cut-off date for ChatGPT is before its emergence. The term "Google" is ambiguous since it refers to both the name of the company and the lead product, which is also used as a prefix for many products they offer. When it comes to the search engine, the results are personalized, so each person's experience is unique. To make it relevant for this discussion, if mentioning that the original poster used a bot or searched the web, more specific details should be provided.

Answer (score 4):

## It depends on the individual company/product owner.

Generally, White Hat Hackers are hired or invited into a program called [Bug Bounty Program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bug_bounty_program) or Vulnerability Reward Program (VRP), but they can also do their work on software that they are unauthorized. They are [hackers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacker) anyway. They can do things on their own.

For those who participate in the mentioned programs, they will be rewarded according to the agreement stated in such programs. However, those that do without permission will have many possible outcomes from such action. It can be anything from getting paid, public recognition, or even recruitment. They can also be investigated for unauthorized access though, but this choice is less likely.

Therefore, it really depends on the individual company in order to decide whether to reward those white hat hackers or not. If so then the reward is decided by the company, which again really depends on the company to decide.

*Note: This post answers in a general aspect of the question because this information is not specific to GenAI field.*

Comment: It's possible that the term "hackers" can be interpreted in various ways, so it may be helpful to briefly clarify what you mean by using this term, especially since this community is relatively new. Doing so could improve the effectiveness of this answer.

Comment: @Wicket Edited to add a reference to a wiki link for further read about "hacker" definition.

Answer (score 2):

It depends, as mentioned in [holydragon's answer](https://genai.stackexchange.com/a/326/12). The way to handle the participation of "white hat hackers" depends on each company, organizational unit, and sometimes on the product owner and maintainer.

One example is [Google AI's Red Team](https://blog.google/technology/safety-security/googles-ai-red-team-the-ethical-hackers-making-ai-safer/) (published on Jul 19, 2023):

> ##### What is red teaming?
>
> Google Red Team consists of a team of hackers that simulate a variety of adversaries, ranging from nation states and well-known Advanced Persistent Threat (APT) groups to hacktivists, individual criminals or even malicious insiders. The term came from the military, and described activities where a designated team would play an adversarial role (the “Red Team”) against the “home” team.

---

I think this question deserves an explanation about what is a *white hat hacker* as there might be misunderstanding due to different uses of the *hacker* term.

The term *hacker* originally referred to people that solve technical problems in unusual ways, and it hasn't any legal or ethical implicit meaning. Later this term becomes popular among computer usage enthusiasts.

As time has passed, the term "hacker" has taken on various meanings. For instance, individuals might claim that their computer was "hacked" when it malfunctions, effectively blaming the supposed perpetrator for the unexpected behavior. The terms "black hat" and "white hat" were originally used to distinguish between the villains and heroes in Western movies. The bad characters were portrayed wearing black hats while the good characters wore white hats.

Another term used is "Red team" inspired by competitions where one team wears blue and another red. Some use "Red team" to refer to people simulating to be the "enemy".

Despite the label used, companies might have employees responsible for analyzing risks, finding vulnerabilities and ways to exploit them using methods that are not part of the company's standard practices. Companies might also have programs to attract volunteers to contribute to their risk management efforts. They might use multiple ways to motivate the parts involved.

Reference

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacker

Answer (score 1):

> Are white hat hackers rewarded for identifying genAI's vulnerabilities?

OpenAI [doesn't](https://bugcrowd.com/openai) financially reward that kind of feedback:

> Issues related to the content of model prompts and responses are strictly out of scope, and will not be rewarded unless they have an additional directly verifiable security impact on an in-scope service (described below).

Comment: I'm confused.  The link seems to give a definitive "yes" ($200 – $6,500 per vulnerability), but this answer says "no".

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones "Issues related to the content of model prompts and responses are strictly out of scope, and will not be rewarded unless they have an additional directly verifiable security impact on an in-scope service (described below)."

Comment: Downvoting the only answer linking to an actual company source that answers the question. Good job.